# RobotFramework AutoItLibrary.Run test case passing, but no window shown

Tags: automated-testing, python, robotframework, autoit

I have Python 3.7.0, Robot Framework 3.2.2, and AutoItLibrary 1.2.7 installed. I have the following test case to simply run an app I have developed in .NET:

```
*** Settings ***
Library           AutoItLibrary

*** Variables ***
${APP_PATH}       C:\\path\\to\\my\\app.exe
${SW_SHOW}        5

*** Test Cases ***
TC0
    Run    ${APP_PATH}    ${EMPTY}    ${SW_SHOW}
```

Running the test with `robot test_case.robot` *passes* the test case, but no window shows? What is the cause of this? Strangely, replacing `${APP_PATH}` with `notepad.exe` opens the Notepad window correctly.

Comment: `Run` should return a value from which you can tell if the launch was successful or not. What is this value in your example? Or you can see if a new process is running. It also might be in the flag, I don't know if value 5 is correct, if it's not ignored etc.

Comment: Where can I find the return value? I checked the command line and log file.

Comment: I guess this should work `${return_value}=    Run    ${APP_PATH}    ${EMPTY}    ${SW_SHOW}`, then you can log the value to console for example.

Comment: @pavelsaman ok, using a variable like that, I got the value 36680

Comment: That looks like a PID to me, so it seems your app.exe has been launched, so you need to figure out why you don't see any window.